# Pygame - calling surface.convert() on animated sprite causes transparent background to become white

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, transparent, geometry-surface

Everyone says to use `.convert()` on surfaces to speed up animations (which will be an issue with my game because it will be an MMO to some extent, so it might have a dozen or a couple dozen characters moving at the same time), the problem is that my transparent PNG images work great without convert but as soon as I use `.convert()` all of the transparent backgrounds suddenly become white

Do I need to sample the color and make it transparent using color_key?

Answer (score 3):

`convert_alpha` should do the trick

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.convert_alpha

Comment: Is there a reason you're not upvoting this answer? Failing to do contributes to clutter on the "unanswered questions" list.